# Do $\epsilon,\hat\epsilon$ exist such that $\hat\epsilon\hat\theta=\theta\epsilon$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let:

- $G$ be a group;
- $H\le G$;
- $\theta,\hat\theta$ be Cayley embeddings.

[image]

> Do there exist embeddings $\epsilon:H \to G$ and $\hat\epsilon:{\rm Sym}(H) \to {\rm Sym}(G)$ such that the above diagram commutes; i.e. such that $\hat\epsilon\hat\theta=\theta\epsilon$?

The only I can think of for $\epsilon$ is either the natural one ($\epsilon(h)=h$) or by conjugacy ($\epsilon(h)=ghg^{-1}$), while for $\hat\epsilon(\sigma)$ is the extension of $\sigma \in \operatorname{Sym}(H)$ by the identity map of $G\setminus H$, but I didn't come to a conclusion with them.

Comment: Yes and the proof is routine.

Comment: $\epsilon(h)=h$ works.

Comment: @Derek Holt I find $((\theta\epsilon)(h))(g)=hg, \forall h \in H, \forall g \in G$, but -with my guessed $\hat\epsilon$- $((\hat\epsilon\hat\theta)(h))(g)=hg$ only for $g \in H$. Either I'm wrongly applying my $\hat\epsilon$'s definition or -more probably- it's another $\hat\epsilon$ which does the job.

Comment: Choose coset representatives $g_i$ of $h$ in $G$ and for $\sigma \in {\rm Sym}(H)$ define $\hat{\epsilon}(\sigma)(hg_i) = \sigma(h)g_i$.

Comment: The question as posed makes no sense. If you write "Let $\epsilon$ be blah blah" then at this point, this variable is fixed. You can't then ask "does $\epsilon$ exist such that..." What you can ask is "does $\epsilon$ have the following property". If you don't want to specify $\epsilon$ from the start, but want to find one that is an embedding, you should remove it from your intro and then ask "Does there exist an embedding $\epsilon$ such that..." I find many of your questions have this problem which makes them very confusing.

Comment: So the comments make no sense either?

Comment: My guess is that Derek automatically translated to the question that you probably wanted to ask. (It's sort of possible to guess what you're trying to say, but you should probably try to improve your syntax in the future.)

Comment: I have edited the question to make it correspond to my interpretation thereof!

Comment: @Derek Holt - Yes, that's what I meant.